# How was create function of res.partner called in res.user?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

When I create a user, a res.partner object is automatically created. So,I want to add a many2one field to res.partner class. And I inherit the res.partner class and override the create method.

When I debug using pdb.set_trace, there is no value for departmentid. What I want to do is to add departmentid to "values" dictionary before calling the create function of res.partner. Thanks

class ResPartner(models.Model):
...
department_id = field.Many2one('hr.department', 'Department')

Comment: Can you please add some more code (formatted please) and explain the process of setting the department? Usually you add the field like in your code above. Since `res.users` inherits `res.partner` you can add the field in the `res.users` form view, to let someone set it before creation. There is no more magic about that. If you want to let Odoo decide which department to set, use the default parameter on that field. Just a hint: the partner is created before the user!

Comment: I added the departent_id (many2one) in the res.users form view. So if I create a user with a particular department_id, I want to have that department_id in res.partner table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code.

```
     class ResPartner(models.Model):
       _inherit = 'res.partner'

       @api.model
       def create(self, vals):
          if self.department_id:
               vals['department_id'] = self.department_id

          return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks, but got this error when  I run it.
AttributeError: module 'odoo.api' has no attribute 'model_create_multi'

Comment: can you please specify the odoo version ?

Comment: I am using odoo 11

Comment: I updated the code according to odoo 11.Check it and let me know if any issues.

Comment: There is no department_id in vals. What I want to do is to have department_id before calling this method. But this method is automatically called when I create a user. Thanks you!

Comment: 'department_id', is in the user form right ? when you create a user you have to select the department_id from the field right ?

Comment: Yeah, I did select the department when I create a new user. And yes department_id is in the user form.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to create a partner with some department value while creating a user. For that you have to mention the department in user. You have to create a new field 'department_id' in user for department as you did in partner. and write the below code in partner create function

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    if vals.get('user_id',False):
        user_id = self.env['res.users'].browse(vals.get('user_id',False))
        vals.update({'department_id': user_id.department_id and user_id.department_id.id or False})
    return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
```

Edit 1:
Please create a new field in res users as below:

```
department_id = field.Many2one('hr.department', related="partner_id.department_id", 'Department')
```

Then you just avoid the create function. This field declaration will solve you problem, Also select a department from res users form view.

Comment: email : False
image : False
property_payment_term_id : False
type : contact
tz : Europe/Brussels
customer : True
invoice_warn : no-message
property_account_position_id : False
trust : normal
name : Corvus
property_account_payable_id : False
payment_next_action : False
property_account_receivable_id : False
message_bounce : 0
payment_next_action_date : False
is_company : False
category_id : [(6, 0, [])]


These are the keys and values in the dictionary 'vals'. I want to have department_id in this dictionary from res.users. Thanks you, but still doesn't work! :")

Comment: There is no department_id in vals. What I want to do is to have department_id before calling this method. But this method is automatically called when I create a user. Thanks you!

Comment: Please be informed  that in vals we only have user_id we have to browse and get the department. Please refer my code

Comment: Don't know but when I check the user_id, it is False: :")

Comment: Please look in to my answer. I have made some changes

Comment: Please ensure that you have given dependency to base and also there is a partner_id field in user form view